# SQL - How to stitch two rows from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 20 Million rows.

Every row represents a day + client.

Not all days are represented by rows.

I need to fetch for a range of dates, lets say 2015-01-01 to 2016-01-01 a table, that will have for each client the row closest from above to 2015-01-01, and closest from below to 2016-01-01

Table:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

To sum up, this is 2 rows from the same table stitched into one row.

Just selecting and joining takes forever. What is the right way to query this data?

Comment: Do post the query that you have tried and also post the tables and data as text instead of images so that other may try them out. You say your join is very slow. Can you post the explain output too?

Comment: Is there a primary key column in this table that uniquely identifies each row ?

Comment: I think your example data is confused.  How would client 2 get the value of 213 when in only appears in the table for client 1?  How would client 2 have a date of 2015-01-01 when that doesn't appear in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches.  Perhaps the simplest is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` hack:

```
select client, min(date) as date1, max(date) as date2,
       substring_index(group_concat(random order by date), ',', 1) as random1,
       substring_index(group_concat(random order by date desc), ',', 1) as random2
from t
where date >= '2015-01-01' and
      date < '2016-01-01'
group by client;
```

Given your sample data, this should run fine.

A more traditional approach would use aggregation and joins:

```
select c.client, c.date1, c.date2, t1.random as random1, t2.random as random2
from (select t.client, min(date) as date1, max(date) as date2
      from t
      where date >= '2015-01-01' and date < '2016-01-01'
      group by client
     ) c join
     t t1
     on c.client = t1.client and c.date1 = t1.date join
     t t2
     on c.client = t2.client and c.date2 = t2.date;
```

This also makes it easier to add more than two data columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to using two dependent subqueries - but this may not be very efficient, MySql is not very clever in optimizing dependent subqueries.:

```
SELECT client,
       date as date1,
       (  SELECT date FROM table t2
          WHERE t1.client = t2.client
            AND t2.date > t1.date
          ORDER BY t2.date LIMIT 1
        ) as date2,
       random As random1,
       (  SELECT random FROM table t2
          WHERE t1.client = t2.client
            AND t2.date > t1.date
          ORDER BY t2.date LIMIT 1
       ) as random2     
FROM table t1
```

You can create a multicolumn index on `table(client, date)` to speed this query up.

Comment: It is very slow. especially when I dont have just 2 columns, but 10

Comment: If the table would have a primary key (a surrogate PK), then there had been possible a solution with a join  - but you didn't mention it in the question if the table has any PK, so I assume that there is no PK, and this solution is not possible in this case.